# A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed with autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac, .net-7.0

I add injection dependency in an ASP.NET Core 7 MVC project.

My project has multiple `DbContext`. I try to do have a `baseContext` like [mother class.](https://muratsuzen.medium.com/using-multiple-dbcontext-on-net-6-web-api-with-repository-pattern-3d223874e625)

I update my repositories in async and I change all static BLL class to service with interfaces.

Actually I get an error

> A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.

PS: excuse my English.

```
public class HomeController : IntranetController
{
    private readonly ITileParameterDisplayValueService tileParameterDisplayValueService;
    private readonly ITileTemplateService tileTemplateService;
    private readonly ITileService tileService;
    private readonly ITileTileParameterService tiletileparameterService;
    private readonly IUserIntranetService userIntranetService;
    private readonly ITileParameterService tileParameterService;

    public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment host,
        ICarrierFormService carrierFormService,
        ITileParameterDisplayValueService tileParameterDisplayValueService,
        ITileTemplateService tileTemplateService,
        ITileService tileService,
        ITileTileParameterService tiletileparameterService,
        IUserIntranetService userIntranetService,
        ITileParameterService tileParameterService,
        INotificationService notificationService,
        IUserIntranetRepository userIntranetRepository,
        ICityZipCodeService cityZipCodeService) : base(host, notificationService, userIntranetRepository, cityZipCodeService, carrierFormService)
    { 
        this.tileParameterDisplayValueService  = tileParameterDisplayValueService;
        this.tileTemplateService = tileTemplateService;
        this.tileService = tileService;
        this.tiletileparameterService = tiletileparameterService;
        this.userIntranetService = userIntranetService;
        this.tileParameterService = tileParameterService;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {    
        await LoadSessionAsync();
        return View();
    }
}
```

```
public class IntranetController : Controller
{
     private readonly INotificationService notificationService;
     //private readonly IUserIntranetService userIntranetService;
     private readonly IUserIntranetRepository userIntranetRepository;
     private readonly ICityZipCodeService cityZipCodeService;

     public IWebHostEnvironment Host { get; set; }

     private DateTime StartTimestamp { get; set; }

     internal LoggerUser LoggerUser { get; set; }

     protected ICarrierFormService carrierFormService;

     public IntranetController(IWebHostEnvironment host,
         INotificationService notificationService,
         //IUserIntranetService userIntranetService,
         IUserIntranetRepository userIntranetRepository,
         ICityZipCodeService cityZipCodeService,
         ICarrierFormService carrierFormService)
     {
         Host = host;
         this.carrierFormService = carrierFormService;
         this.notificationService = notificationService;
         //this.userIntranetService = userIntranetService;
         this.userIntranetRepository = userIntranetRepository;
         this.cityZipCodeService = cityZipCodeService;
    }

    protected async Task LoadSessionAsync()
    {
        // Récupération de l'utilisateur
        string userName = CurrentApplication.GetUserName(User.Identity.Name);
        UserIntranet user = await userIntranetRepository.SelectByLoginAsync(userName);
    }
}
```

```
public class UserIntranetRepository : IUserIntranetRepository
{
    private readonly DbCommonContext _context;

    public UserIntranetRepository(DbContextFactory contexts)
    {
         var baseContext = contexts.GetContext("DbCommonContext");
         _context = (DbCommonContext)baseContext;
    }
   
    public async Task<UserIntranet> SelectByLoginAsync(string login)
    {
        return await _context.UsersIntranet.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Login == login) as UserIntranet;
    }
}
```

When I debug I go through the repository twice. Does passing services in the `UserIntranetService` constructor

Comment: What is the lifetime of your db context?